# load jquery dropdown before javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4

**Goal**: Website loads correct image path first time opened

**Issue**: Upon first load the path is incorrect, after refreshing it loads the correct path.

**Current approach**: I have a jquery function that reads in a text file listing dates (part of the image file name) and populates a dropdown menu (this is working).

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        let dropdown = $('#locality-dropdown');
        dropdown.empty();
        const url = './figures/model/all_model/sic/maps_weekly/plotdates_current.json'

        // Populate dropdown with list of provinces
        $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
         $.each(data, function (key, entry) {
           dropdown.append($('<option> selected="true" </option>').attr('value', entry.date).text(entry.date));
         })
        });
      </script>
```

I have another function UpdateImage() that is called onload, that reads in the first dropdown item (a date) and builds the path to the image to display.

```
      <script>    

     function UpdateImage() {

         FI = pad(document.form1.FI.value, 2);
         variable = document.form1.variable.value;
         metric = document.form1.metric.value;
         idate = document.getElementById("locality-dropdown").value;
         console.log(idate);
         if (FI=='99') {
             ext = '.gif';
         } else {
             ext = '.png'
         }
         document.image1.src = "./figures/model/all_model/"+variable+"/maps_weekly/panArctic_"+metric+"_forecast_"+
             idate+"_"+FI+ext+"?342038402";
     }
  </script>
```

**Question**: How can I force the jquery function to populate the dropdown before the javascript UpdateImage() function is called?

I tried putting the jquery function before the javascript, but this did not work.

**Full Code is at: https://atmos.uw.edu/sipn/panarcticmaps.html**

(Also, I am new to html/javascript/jquery so apologies for poorly written code and framed questions)

Comment: Simply do not call the `UpdateImage()` until jQuery is done.

Comment: `UpdateImage` must be invoked inside `$.getJSON` callback function. Or you can use `Promise`.

Comment: Thank you @vnt! Putting UpdateImage() inside the `$.getJSON` callback function worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @vnt suggested, putting UpdateImage() inside the $.getJSON callback function worked.